# Parallelization

Tags: parallelization

I am new to mathematica and have the following question regarding parallelization of the code. I have an input data which is of the form

```
data = Import["data.dat", "Table"]
```

Then I create a module which executes various line of code and then use the module to do the following.

```
Table[module[data[[i]]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

This works perfectly fine the only problem is that it takes a lot of time close to 15 minutes as there is a differential equation which it has to execute 10 times. Then I tried ParallelTable but it does not work effectively. Thus I tried parallelising the code using ParallelSubmit as follows.

```
tab = ParallelSubmit[Table[module[data[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}]]
WaitAll[%]
```

This gives me the error

> Part specification data[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

This is just a sample of 10 points under consideration and in the actual sitation it may include 20 or more points.

It would be of great help if someone could help me resolve the problem.

I have made the following changes 
1) `Table[ParallelSubmit[module[data[[j]]]], {j, 1, 3}]` 
I get the error

> The expression j cannot be used as a part specification.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour]**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I dont know about the error, but you should review the docs for `ParallelSubmit`.  `ParallelSubmit` should be applied to the expression inside the table, not the table itself. There is a example of exactly that in the docs.

Comment: can you please expand on *" I tried `ParallelTable` but it does not work effectively"*. Share the code you tried, why didn't it work? Did you `DistributeDefinitions`? How big is the data? There is an overhead moving the data to other kernels. Are the other kernels remote or local?

Comment: I have included it in the function and get the following error  The expression i cannot be used as a part specification

Comment: re: edit.. you must give `{j}` as the first arg to `ParallelSubmit` (as in the docs).   That said, I think you should go back and figure out what was wrong with your `ParallelTable` implementation.  (I'd use `ParallelSubmit` only if your module calls are wildly unbalanced )

Comment: Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, moduleburkert[databurkert[[i]]]], {i, 1, 
  10}] The for a similar code is Part specification databurkert[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us the **data** and the `Module`. If too long or proprietary sometimes one can make a smaller simple version of **data** and/or `Module` that has the same problem. It is easier for members to tackle the problem with that information.

Comment: To reiterate rhermans's point, did you use `DistributeDefinitions[data]` before trying `ParallelTable`?

Comment: You can also try (at least for debugging purpose ) `CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[]` just before `ParallelWhatever` to ensure all of your parallel kernels start fresh with all symbols defined.

Comment: DistributeDefinitions[data] gives {} and after closing and lauching kernels it now takes 10 mins.